# How would I have the 'this' keyword in a setTimeout parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have the following code with the purpose of making each `.feedcontain` div fade in after an increasing delay. The animation and formatting is perfect, its just that I can't have a `this` keyword in the first `setTimeout()` parameter.

```
function goFadeNow(){
    var loopdelay=250;
    $(".feedcontain").each(function() {
        setTimeout('$('+this+').addClass("appeared");',loopdelay);
        //$(this).addClass("appeared");
        loopdelay=loopdelay+250;
    });
}
```

If I uncomment line 5 and comment line 4, it works but it doesn't have the delay. PS: I do realize that I can't just use `this` like a normal variable.

Answer (score 3):

You can also `bind()` the function you are passing to `this` pointer:

```
function timeoutFunc() {
  $(this).addClass("appeared");
}

function goFadeNow(){
  var loopdelay=250;

  $(".feedcontain").each(function() {
    setTimeout(timeoutFunc.bind(this), loopdelay);
    loopdelay=loopdelay+250;
  });
}
```

Comment: What advantage do you think this offers over Matt's answer if any and why?

Comment: Matt's solution saves the context of `goFadeNow` function, but the author of the question asked to pass the context of `each` function. The idea is the same, but we can operate with different meanings of `this` in the `timeoutFunc` just rebinding it do different contexts.

Answer (score 2):

```
function goFadeNow(){
    var loopdelay=250;
    $(".feedcontain").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $this.addClass("appeared");
        }, loopdelay);
        loopdelay=loopdelay+250;
    });
}
```

Comment: Why did you both answer and close vote?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4283/closing-etiquette-why-do-some-answer-and-close/4288#4288

Comment: This solution is not quite right: you are always adding class `appeared` to the same `$this` element. But @ScorpionByte probably wanted to add this css class to each element returned by jQuery selector. To do that you should have saved `$(this)` inside function passed into `each` before calling `setTimeout`.

Comment: @AlexArgutin whoops, you're totally right! I shouldn't answer when tired. Sorry; fixed.